# Orthographe de « diagnostic » et « pronostic »

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, grec

Je me demande comment s'explique la différence entre l'orthographe du mot **diagnostic** et celle du mot **pronostic**. Tous les deux (ainsi que **pronostique** et **diagnostique**) viennent de la langue grecque et des mots *prognosis* et *diagnosis*, respectivement. La lettre g correspondant à la lettre grecque gamma (γ) est restée dans le mot **diagnostic** mais pas dans le mot **pronostic**.

Pourquoi cette différence ?

Comment: Hmm! I wouldn't have thought it breaks down this way but [you're absolutely right](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dianostic%2Cdiagnostique%2Cpronostic%2Cprognostique&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdianostic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdiagnostique%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdiagnostique%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDIAGNOSTIQUE%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDiagnostique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpronostic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpronostic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPronostic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPRONOSTIC%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprognostique%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est probablement une question d'époque de l'emprunt au grec.

Les langues évoluent avec le temps et les mots s'altèrent. `Pronostic` est attesté en français depuis le Moyen-Âge. `Diagnostic` est attesté depuis le XVIIIème siècle. Les mots les plus anciens ont davantage le temps de s'altérer, donc `pronostic` a dû perdre son g avec le temps.

A noter d'ailleurs que dans les formes anciennes, `pronostic` s'écrivait effectivement `prognostic`.

Note : pour les dates, je me suis fié à [ce lien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diagnostic) et [ce lien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pronostic).

Il y a de nombreux exemples, parfois même avec le même mot. Par exemple, un emprunt ancien au latin `fragilis` a donné le français `frêle`, alors qu'un nouvel emprunt plus récent à donné `fragile`, qui est plus fidèle à la forme d'origine.

Answer (score 4):

Juste pour me permettre de faire observer que si, effectivement, le *diagnostic* français est un emprunt direct au grec (tardif), le *pronostic* français est quant à lui emprunté au **bas latin.**

Pour le français qui, ainsi que l'italien d'ailleurs, a laissé tomber le *g* de *co**g**noscere*, je crois le fait de cet emprunt immédiat au latin pas innocent dans l'affaire.